# How can I switch between devtools panels with a keyboard shortcut on Mac OS X?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Everywhere I look, including Google's own [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts) as well as the "Shortcuts" option in the DevTools menu, says that the keyboard shortcuts to switch between DevTools panels should be `Cmd + [` and `Cmd + ]`. However, for me this keyboard shortcut acts as the Previous/Next buttons on my browser, and takes me through my browsing history. This occurs even if I am focused into the DevTools.

I'd like to be able to switch between DevTools panels (such as Elements, Console, Sources, etc.) with a keyboard shortcut. Is this possible? If so, how?

If it matters, I'm on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 and I'm using Google Chrome version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit). Google Chrome is up-to-date currently. Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Command`+`[` is working for me on macOS 10.12.3 / Chrome 58.

I know you said you're focused on DevTools, but it sounds like something is interfering with that.

Try [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html), which is the bleeding-edge release of Chrome. If it's fixed there, then it may have just been a regression.

Update: I just tried it with Chrome 56 and can reproduce. It's just a regression.

Comment: The shortcut functions correctly for me in Canary as well. Thanks.